# New Line in Cell to New Row Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that will take a cell and split character strings separated by new lines into new rows. To demonstrate what I mean visually, if I have a cell that looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this after I run the macro:
[image]

Right now I'm using the following code for my macro which clearly has something wrong with it:

```
Sub splitText()

Dim splitVals As Variant

Dim totalVals As Long

splitVals = Split(ActiveCell.Value, Chr(10))

totalVals = UBound(splitVals)

Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1 + totalVals, ActiveCell.Column)).Value = splitVals

Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Instead of splitting it like I'd prefer it just copies the string before the first line break and copies that into the following cells

[image]

How can I change my code to work correctly?

Comment: [Transpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose) `splitVals` first?

Comment: @GSerg where in the code should I insert that?

Comment: Apparently after you fill `splitVals`, but before you copy it to the sheet.